# Subsetting based on standard deviation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, trim

I have a data frame that consists of columns of variables for each observation, which are rows. I need to trim this data to remove unwanted observations.

How I usually do this -

```
trimmed_stats <- ddply(.data = data, .(pos), subset,
                       !AvgGFP > 100 &
                       !AvgRFP > 60 &
                       !Area < 220 &
                       !Area > 2000 &
                       !DeviationsRFP > 20 &
                       !DeviationGFP > 20)
```

...Essentially removing data that do not meet a certain criteria.

However when I am looking at multiple data sets, these specific numbers are going to vary from set to set.

What I want to do is perform the "trimming" using standard deviations from the mean.

For example, let's take a simple data frame with one variable for each observation -

```
p <- data.frame(obs = c(1:1000), var1 = rnorm(1000, 0 , 5))
sd(p[,2])
[1] 4.91213
```

So 1 standard deviation is 4.91213, how can I remove all rows where var1 does not lie within 1 standard deviation of the mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `subset` function does allow you to use computed values, so you can do:

```
trimmed_stats <- ddply(.data = data, .(pos), subset,
                       abs(AvgGFP - mean(AvgGFP)) < sd(AvgGFP) &
                       ...)
```

and don't be mistaken: within `ddply`, these `mean(AvgGFP)` and `sd(AvgGFP)` are indeed computed for each `pos`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
p <- data.table(p)
p[,ToKeep := abs(var1-mean(var1)) < sd(var1)][ToKeep  == TRUE]
```

Answer (score -2):

I am new to R. Try if the following codes work for your situation.

`p_new <- p[which(p[,2] <= sd(p[,2])), ]`

In the p_new, all the rows with var1 larger than 1 standard deviation of the mean has been removed.